# Real Analysis Uniform Continuity Question help

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is uniformly continuous on a bounded subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is bounded on $A$.

How would i start my proof? Could anybody give me a hint? I

Comment: a sequence can be thought of as a set of countably many points. Sequences are certainly not just *elements* of the set, anyway.  Also, remember that $\{y_n\}$ is a sequence in $f(A)$; if you are to follow the deleted approach, you should consider the sequence $\{x_n\} \subset A$ such that for each $n$, $y_n = f(x_n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to the problem: suppose that $f(A)$ is unbounded

- Since $f(A)$ is unbounded, there must be a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$ is $\infty$ or $-\infty$
- Note that bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are totally bounded; that is, every sequence in $A$ will have a Cauchy subsequence
- Note that $f$ is uniformly continuous, which means it maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

Putting these three together, you can derive a contradiction and force the conclusion that $f(A)$ is bounded.

Copper's first approach is the more common one, and if I recall correctly it pops up in Rudin somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! For the first dot point, wouldn't it be if $f(A)$ is unbounded? And also, would this approach have something to do with the Continuous Extension Theorem?

Comment: Yes, I mean unbounded.  And yes, this approach is connected to the continuous extension theorem.  If you are aware of the continuous extension theorem, then I would use that approach (as suggested by copper.hat) instead.

Comment: Note, however, that my approach does not require the extension theorem, and we make no reference to an extension of our function.

Comment: I am aware of the Continuous Extension Theorem but my textbook (Introduction to Real Analysis, Bartle&Sherbert) doesn't have the term "compact" or the "closure of A" in the Theorem. So I will just follow your approach.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate more on the third dot point? What does that exactly mean? Sorry that I am asking a lot of questions.

Comment: Not a problem.  I'm assuming you know what a Cauchy sequence is.  All I'm saying is that if $\{z_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then if $f$ is uniformly continuous, $\{f(z_n)\}$ is also Cauchy.

Comment: To use copper hat's approach (without knowing what $\bar A$ means), note that the interior of $A$ can be written as the countable union of (disjoint) sets of the form $(a,b)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15086/discussion-between-user143391-and-omnomnomnom).

Answer (score 3):

Hint for one approach:

If $\delta>0$, how many balls of radius $\delta$ are needed to cover $A$?

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < 1$ as long as $|x-y| < \delta$ and $x,y \in A$. It takes at most a finite number of sets of the form $\{y | |y-k \delta| < \delta \}$ to cover $A$. Call them $B_i$, with $i=1,...n$. Pick any point $x_i \in B_i$. Then show that $f$ is bounded by $\max(f(x_1),...,f(x_n))+1$.

Hint for another approach:

Can you extend $f$ to $\bar{A}$?

> If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$, it can be extended to a continuous function $\bar{f}$ on $\bar{A}$, the closure of $A$. Note that $\bar{A}$ is compact, hence $\bar{f}$ has a $\min$, $\max$. Hence $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have never seen the terms you are using before (balls of radius and the A with a line on it)..My textbook probably requires a different approach.

Comment: I mean sets of the form $\{ y| |x-y < \delta \}$. By $\bar{A}$, I mean the closure of $A$.

Comment: I added some elaboration, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you I'll work on it!